# With ember-rapid-forms. how can I store the password securely?

Tags: ember.js

With ember-rapid-forms, one typically uses a model for handling the various input parameters in the form.

However, if the input type is `password`, then it will be part of the model and the user could retrieve it in plaintext. Rather unfortunate with auto-complete and possible reuse of previous passwords.

How can I avoid that with ember-rapid-forms?

Comment: You generally don't send the password back from your backend to the frontend

Comment: I don't, I put it in a model that lives for a few more pages before it is saved at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is an abstraction issue here.

I was about to write a section about how to hash the password and explain that this is what a back end server would do anyway then I realized how silly that is.

First the user enters a password. It is now a given that the user *knows* the password. They have rights to view the password in plaintext because that is how autocompletes and password managers work. This is no different then copy/pasting the password into a text file. No website manages this because the user has already entered the password.

Then I thought were concerned about the field being of type `text` and not `password` but I just looked at the `ember-rapid-forms` site and they support `type="password"`.

After that I thought maybe you are concerned that the user will open a console and extract the password. But in that case the user just entered the password so that is plain silly. But what about an man in the middle injecting code into the Ember app. Well if this were the case why dive into the Ember code when JavaScript could just tap into the DOM for the input tag and get the plaintext there. Again this is a theoretical idea and is something no website I know of attempts to protect against. It is far more likely that the user will be abducted and tortured for the password then have client side JavaScript be exploited. Besides if that was the intent it is far easier to exploit the operating system then the Ember code.

After that diatribe I tried really hard to understand where you were coming from and what you were attempting to protect against. You mentioned autocomplete and reuse. In these cases I'm not sure what examples you have that Ember would not be doing anyway. No website I know uses unconventional means to protect a user entering a password from autocompletes from the browser or a password manager. Come to think of it if a password manager auto fills in the password why would the user open a console to get the plain text when they could just open the password manager's admin interface.

As for password reuse I can't imagine a scenario where an Ember application would have knowledge of other webpages/applications use of the same password.